# Insert variables into a HTML template in Django view then return via AJAX

Tags: html, ajax, django, templates

I have a HTML template that I need to be repeated but with different variables from a set of data.

It will be better explained if I show you my current code:

```
def getBlueWidgets(request):
    widgets = Widget.objects.filter(colour='blue')
    html = generateHtml(widgets)
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(html), mimetype="application/json")

def generateHtml(widgets):
    html = ''
    for widget in widgets:
        html += '<div class="widget">'
        html += '<div class="title">'
        html += widget.title
        html += '</div></div>'
    return html
```

I call `getBlueWidgets()` via AJAX, then add the HTML to the document with JS. This works fine but isn't very neat and it makes it hard to maintain my widget HTML code. Is there a way I can add my widget template to a .html file, somehow specifying where the variables should be, and import it into `generateHtml()`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You can use [render_to_string](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/api/#the-render-to-string-shortcut):

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

def getBlueWidgets(request):
    widgets = Widget.objects.filter(colour='blue')
    html = render_to_string('widgets.html', {'widgets': widgets})
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(html), mimetype="application/json")

# widgets.html
{% for widget in widgets %}
    <div class="widget">
        <div class="title">{{ widget.title }}</div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```